# fetching last inserted id on Zend

Tags: php, database, zend-framework

I would like to ask how would i know the last inserted id of a record inserted to a table. I am using a Zend_Db_Table_Abstract;

$stuff = new Application_Model_MyStuff_NewStuff();

$stuff->createMyStuff($id = 1, $stuff = "This is a new stuff!");

//when i try to see what id is inserted using this code;

echo $stuff->getAdapter()->lastInsertId();

//it shows a continuous incremented value instead of the actual 'id' field value.

Thanks. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just got it,

http://osdir.com/ml/php.zend.framework.db/2008-04/msg00008.html